# Error unable to read memory from my linked list

Tags: c

I am wondering why my program I just wrote isn't showing any output and why when I try to show output it is saying **Unable to read Memory** It is saying unable to read memory when I follow the code with breakpoints.  I am new to coding and Just wondering why it is saying that. I do believe a lot of the issues with this code does come from the linked list function `MovieNode* getMovieInfo(MovieNode* ptr, char title[], char genre[]);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>


typedef struct MovieNode {
    
    char* title; 
    char* genre; 
    MovieNode* next; 
}MovieNode;

//Constants 
#define kInfiniteLoop 1
#define kCharacterString 30 

//Prototypes
void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer);
MovieNode* getMovieInfo(MovieNode* ptr, char title[], char genre[]);
void printMovieInfo(MovieNode* head);
bool isEmpty(MovieNode* head); 

int main() {

    MovieNode* head = NULL; 
    char title[kCharacterString];
    char genre[kCharacterString]; 
     
    
    printf("Enter Titles and Genres into my linked list\n"); 
    printf("Enter'.' to get out of the loop and print list\n"); 

    while (kInfiniteLoop) {

        printf("Title:"); 
        fgets(title, kCharacterString, stdin); 
        eliminateEndOfLine(title);

        if (strcmp(title, ".")==0) {
            break; 
        }
        printf("Genre:");
        fgets(genre, kCharacterString, stdin);
        eliminateEndOfLine(genre);

        getMovieInfo(head, title, genre); 
    }

    printMovieInfo(head);

    return 0;
}

MovieNode* getMovieInfo(MovieNode* ptrHead, char title[], char genre[]) {

    MovieNode* link = (MovieNode*)malloc(sizeof(MovieNode)); 

    link->title=(char*)malloc(strlen(title) + 1); 

    link->genre = (char*)malloc(strlen(title) + 1); 

    strcpy(link->title, title); 
    strcpy(link->genre, genre); 

    if (!isEmpty(ptrHead)) {
        return ptrHead;
    }

    link->next = ptrHead;
    ptrHead = link; 

    return ptrHead; 
}
```

```
 - I believe a lot of the issue is  from the function above that is
   trying to store the data into the linked list.

 
    void printMovieInfo(MovieNode* head) {
        MovieNode* ptr; 
        ptr = head; 
    
        while (ptr != NULL) {     //Right here is where it is saying unable to read memory 
            printf("%35s %35s", ptr->title, ptr->genre);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    
    bool isEmpty(MovieNode *head) {
        return head == NULL;
    }
    
    
    /*=======================================================================================================*/
    /*FUCNTION      :void eliminateEndOfLine                                                                 */
    /*PARAMETER     :(char* buffer)                                                                          */
    /*RETURNS       :void                                                                                    */
    /*DESCRIPTION   :This function takes a pointer to a string and looks through the string to find the      */
    /*               newline.It takes the new line out of the string.                                        */
    /*=======================================================================================================*/
    void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer)
    {
        char* target = strchr(buffer, '\n');
        if (target != NULL)
        {
            *target = '\0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use the debugger to find the exact line of code that first triggers the error and post in in the question.

Comment: In `getMovieInfo` the `link->next` is not set in the case that `if (!isEmpty(ptrHead))` is true and `ptrHead` is not changed to point to the new node as it should.

Comment: How would I change it to support the `if(! isEmpty(ptrHead)) being true?

Comment: `link->next = NULL; return link;` and in `main` you need `head = getMovieInfo(head, title, genre);`

Comment: And you can actually remove the whole `if (!isEmpty(ptrHead))` block completely. It's not needed. If `ptrHead` is NULL the code after the `if` will do the right thing. But you **must** do the `head = getMovieInfo()` in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality which you seems to offer is to get input from user and you store in a struct.

1. make a buffer which recive the input via scanf with escape code to include space and only end input taking when encountered '\n'
2. strcpy the buffer to the struct element.

these steps make no need to remove newline character and make initialization straight forward.

the problem of "unable to read memory" can be solved if you share the real error text here.

pesudocode

```
struct my_type{...}

struct * my_type head = NULL;

char buffer[200] = {0};

int main()
{
    struct * my_type  ptr = head;
    struct * my_type preptr = head;
    while(1)
    {
        ptr = malloc();
        preptr->next = ptr;
        scanf("[^\n%s",&buffer);
        if(strlen(buffer) == 0) break;
        ptr->element = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buffer));
        strcpy(ptr->element, buffer);

        .....//do this till you get desired number of elements
        preptr = ptr;
    }
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr !=NULL)
    {
         printf("%s\n",ptr->element);
         ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

putting this code direct will give error , this is pesudocode to give the ligic which you should implement.